# Representing modus ponens in a Polish propositional logic with NAND as the only connective

Tags: lo.logic

In a base for propositional logic using the Polish connective $\uparrow$ for *not both*, J. Nicod isolated one axiom as sufficient:

$\uparrow\uparrow p\uparrow q r\uparrow\uparrow t\uparrow tt\uparrow\uparrow s q\uparrow\uparrow p s\uparrow ps$

J. Nicod used the somewhat odd inference rule $r$ if $\uparrow p\uparrow q r$ and $p$. May we use $\uparrow p\uparrow r r$ and $p$ instead of Nicod's rule, or is there some deeper reason for including $q$?

Comment: About the title: It seems to me that the rule "infer $r$ from $\uparrow p\uparrow rr$ and $p$" (i.e., in Nicod's rule  replace $q$ with $r$ rather than with $p$) is intuitively closer to modus ponens than the rule you asked about.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you for identifying that typo. I will edit.

Comment: You could really make the format of the second part readable form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

This weakening of Nicod's inference rule is too weak.  The 4-element counter-model above is one on which (a) your rule holds, (b) Nicod's single axioms holds, but (c) the formula s(s(X,X),X) fails to be a theorem (even though it is a classical theorem), where s(•,•) is the sheffer stroke.

Here is the code (3-lines of TPTP format) I used to find this model with mace4.

```
fof(mpweak,axiom, ![X,Z]: ((t(s(X,s(Z,Z))) & t(X)) => t(Z))).

fof(nicod,axiom, ![X,Y,Z,U,V]: t(s(s(X,s(Y,Z)),s(s(V,s(V,V)),s(s(U,Y),s(s(X,U),s(X,U))))))).

fof(luka1,conjecture,![X]: t(s(s(X,X),X))).
```

For a discussion of alternative axiomatizations, I suggest the following article and the references therein.

https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ndjfl/1093958259

Axiomatization of propositional calculus with Sheffer functors.
Thomas W. Scharle
Notre Dame J. Formal Logic
Volume 6, Number 3 (1965), 209-217.

Comment: Welcome to Mathoverflow! I don't understand how the countermodel works, but maybe others can contribute?

Comment: As far as I can see, the Lukasiewicz axiom in the answer differs from the Nicod axiom in the question in that U replaces both $s$ and $t$. Does the Nicod axiom hold in your countermodel?

Comment: Right, sorry, thanks Andreas.   I have fixed this above.  Now a 4-element model is required.  Note that t(•) is the theorem-hood predicate, and c1 = 0 is the instance of s(s(X,X)X) that fails to be a theorem.  i.e., t(s(s(0,0),0)) = 0.

Comment: note, also that Nicod's stronger rule also works with many other known axioms, including Lukaiewicz's.  so, even if somehow this rule had worked with his axiom (in syntactically idiosyncratic way) it would still in this sense have been less generally useful than his stronger rule.

Comment: I accepted this answer because of the very useful literature reference in an edit. Scharle's article settles the question in the negative, but it does not exclude that there are other single axioms in the single connective $\uparrow$ for *not both ,,, and ...* which are adequate for classical propositional logic jointly with normal detachment as  the only inference rule.

Comment: yes, i suspect there is a single axiom for the weaker rule.  i'll be working on this now.

Comment: Note: Scharle's two-basis contains a typo.  Here is a sound and complete 2-axiom system, when combined with your weaker detachment rule (which Scharle calls D3): (1) DpDpp, (2) DDpDqrDDDsqDDpsDpsDDsqDDpsDps

Comment: or, in TPTP format: (1) fof(scharle1,axiom,![X]: t(s(X,s(X,X)))). (2) fof(scharle2,axiom,![X,Y,U,R]: t(s(s(X,s(Y,R)),s(s(s(U,Y),s(s(X,U),s(X,U))),s(s(U,Y),s(s(X,U),s(X,U))))))).

Comment: @BrandenFitelson Thank you very much for this important information.